# Instagram API Platform mobile oAuth Error

Tags: android, ios, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

On mobile web views (iOS UIIWebview, Android WebView) and mobile safari, the following oauth method is failing to progress to the redirect after successful login:

`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code`

It appears to work fine on desktop web.

A quick look at other apps using this API shows we are not alone, does anyone have any info on this issue / potential fixes?

[image: Error Page]

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem in an hybrid ionic cordova application both on iOS and Android. I posted a [question](https://github.com/nraboy/ngx-cordova-oauth/issues/76) also in github with no results

Comment: You might want to subscribe to this bug posted on Facebook: [https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/) currently still waiting for another response, but they've changed the status to 'Investigating'

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have now resolved the issue as per the issued bug report previously mentioned by Giacomo De Liberali
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/

They didn't provide details on what caused the bug, but now it seems like you will be redirected to the new design of the Instagram login form rather than the classic one.